Merely vs only in data reports

Only 12% and 17% of users played games and music on their phones in 2006, respectively.

Can I use merely in place of only in the above sentence? I haven't found any examples of merely preceding data in dictionaries.

I wouldn't advise it. To emphasise the smallness of the figure you could say A mere 12% (I don't know why the adjective is more idiomatic than the adverb here).

I thought about that but there are two figures.

Is "mere 12% and 17%" weird? I haven't seen "mere" (adj) without "a", ever.

That's why I included the article in my example! I didn't bother with the second figure, but it's fine to add it. You can use mere without an article before plural and uncountable nouns.

"merely" followed by a percentage is very well attested in Google Books.  I find "a mere 10%" stronger than "merely 10%"; "a mere" to my ear suggests that the number is so small that it's trifling. "merely 10%" isn't quite as dismissive, at least that's my sense of the nuanced difference.

Whether you use "only", "merely", or "a mere", it's not entirely clear if you mean that to apply just to the 12% or to both figures.

"Mere 12%" sounds weird, but "mere" doesn't always require "a". Mere is also often used with "the" rather than "a": Merriam-Webster gives an example "the mere idea of your traveling alone to Europe is ridiculous". "This mere" and similar are also found. It can be used with uncountable nouns: "mere life" and "mere existence" refer to the lowest level of life without anything pleasurable or elevating. You could also use it with a general plural noun without an article: "Mere animals..." It's commonly used of generalities not specific objects though.

"Only" is both an adjective and an adverb. "Merely" is only an adverb so cannot be applied in the way that "only" is here (i.e. to the percentages of users). The adjective is "mere" and could be used as Kate says in the comments.
You could apply "merely" (or indeed "only") to "played" but that would change the meaning, i.e. "12% and 17% of users [only / merely] played games and music on their phones", meaning that they didn't do anything else.

Only is an adverb. It can be replaced by other adverbs like precisely, exactly, approximately...

@StuartF "only" is definitely both and adjective and an adverb. Are you saying it is only an adverb? If so, where do you get that from?
